# How to get intersection of two arrays in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data like:

```
id  col1     col2
-----------------
1   [1,2]    [2,3]
2   [4,4,6]  [6,7]
```

and I want to have data like:

```
id  col3
---------
1   [2]
2   [6]
```

Any smart solutions for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `INTERSECT DISTINCT`

```
-- build example table
WITH example as (
  SELECT
  * FROM UNNEST([
      STRUCT([1,2] as col1, [2,3] as col2),
      STRUCT([4,4,6],[6,7])
    ])
  )

-- INTERSECT per row on two arrays
SELECT
  ARRAY(SELECT * FROM example.col1
    INTERSECT DISTINCT
    (SELECT * FROM example.col2)
  ) AS result
FROM example
```

Comment: I went ahead and added missing `ARRAY`

Comment: Thank you Mikhail! Your one word modification helped me so much! I could make it with multiple intersection elements.

Comment: I found this way much more faster than using UDF.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider generalizing further as a SQL UDF and leveraging [templated](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#templated-sql-udf-parameters) arguments.  The two arrays would need to share the same element type, and the type must be [comparable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#data-type-properties).

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION array_intersect(x ANY TYPE, y ANY TYPE) AS (
  (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT xe) FROM UNNEST(x) as xe
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT ye FROM UNNEST(y) as ye)
  ON xe = ye)
);
```

And to leverage:

```
SELECT
  array_intersect([1,2,3],[2,3,4]) as i1,
  array_intersect(["a","b","c"],["foo","a"]) as i2
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I solved by myself:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION intersection(x ARRAY<INT64>, y ARRAY<INT64>)
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var res =  x.filter(value => -1 !== y.indexOf(value));
  return res;
;
""";
```

Any other smarter idea is welcome!
Thanks.

Comment: Well your solution was better for my case then the accepted answer, thanks))

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [1,2,3] col1, [2,3] col2, [2,3,7] col3  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, [4,4,6], [6,7], [5,6]
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT DISTINCT a 
    FROM t.col1 a, t.col2 b, t.col3 c 
    WHERE a = b AND b = c
  ) AS result
FROM `project.dataset.your_table` t
```

Above can be more compact especially if you have more than just two columns to process