# BigQuery maximum overlap of array elements across rows

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I have the following data:

| row_id | user | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mark | `[1,2,3]` |
| 2 | Mark | `[1,2,4]` |
| 3 | Mark | `[1]` |
| 4 | Mark | `[3,4]` |
| 5 | Ben | `[1,2,3]` |
| 6 | Ben | `[2]` |

I want the following output

| user | max_intersection |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | [1,2] |
| Ben | [2] |

In other words, I want one row for each user which contains the maximum number of elements in an array that exist in at least 2 rows.

I.e. for Mark [1,2] occur both in row 1 and 2. That [2] doesn't occur in row 3 doesn't matter. [3] is not the answer because that particular row only has an intersection on [3], which is only 1 element overlap, whereas [1,2] contains 2 elements. [1,2,3] is not the answer because though each element occurs at least twice somewhere for the user, the overlap does not occur between two rows but is spread out over more.

If Mark had [1,3] on row 3, making both [1,2] and [1,3] correct, I'd try to get [1,2] because the id number is lower. But it's not the most important

I've tried to adapt the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51748096/3565255) but struggling with the maximum overlap.

Comment: The number 4 does not appear in any of the data values for user Ben. Going by the logic you've explained for user Mark, it is not clear to me how [2,4] is the excepted answer for Ben. I think the answer for user Ben should just be [2].

Comment: @narendra-choudhary you're right, adjusted the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
with temp as (
  select row_id, user, el
  from your_table, unnest(data) el
)
select t1.user, array_agg(t1.el) as max_intersection
from temp t1
join temp t2
on t1.user = t2.user
and t1.row_id < t2.row_id
and t1.el = t2.el
group by user, t1.row_id, t2.row_id
qualify row_number() over(partition by user order by count(*) desc) = 1
```

if to apply to sample data as in your question - output is

[image]