# How can I compare 2 REPEATED/ARRAY columns in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

whats the better way to compare 2 REPEATED(String) or ARRAY(String) in BigQuery?

[Test_Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbdmW.png) (not allowed to paste the image yet)

```
  SELECT 222 as event_id, ["200", "300"] as arr, '2023-01-02' as date_string
  union all 
  SELECT 111 as event_id, ["100", "200"] as arr, '2023-01-01' as date_string
```

This is the table to store the events. I want to compare the `arr` column of these 2 rows and in the result I want to know that 300 is added and 100 is removed in the latest event(i.e event_id 222)

GBQ doesn’t support `ARRAY_DIFF, ARRAY_CONTAINS_, ARRAY_INTERSECT` functions, so any idea? thank you

Comment: your case is not entirely clear to me, but see if the following array offset/sorting concept can help you: SELECT * 
FROM UNNEST ([‘alex’,’howard’,’few’,’blip’,’pristine’,’twin’,’cheers’])
 AS element
WITH OFFSET AS offset
ORDER BY offset;

Comment: Hi @PratikPatil thank you very much for the response. I have updated the question with example data and few more details.

Comment: What's the expected output format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get intersection of two arrays in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746070/how-to-get-intersection-of-two-arrays-in-bigquery)